# How to get the average download speed of a file in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, download, wget

I want to get the download speed of a online file.

In Linux, I can use the following command:

```
wget https://www.sample.com/myfile.exe
```

which will report the average download speed after the download is completed, as below:

```
2021-08-05 21:23:50 (108 MB/s) - â€˜myfile.exe.41â€™ saved [12878248/12878248]
```

In Windows 7, with Chrome or FireFox, during the download progress, I can see the download speed. But after the download, there will no report of the average download speed. Is there a way to get such a value? Or are there any other tools or methods that can do that in Windows, other than find a Dos version of wget?

Comment: Windows 10 includes the `curl` command. `curl -o myfile.exe https://www.sample.com/myfile.exe`. The console output info includes the average download speed.

Comment: @Aenfa, Curl is not a command in windows, it's an executable: *.exe*.